# AngularJs Radiobox group Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

Is there a simple way with Angularjs to Validate a radiogroup that has been instanciated in an extra directive ?

Validation requirement: The User cannot submit unless one of the radioboxes has been clicked.

Here is how I built it :

HTML document :

```
<ng-form name="salutationgroup">
      <radiotrigger model="mrms" name="gender" value='1' label="mr" ></radiotrigger>
      <radiotrigger model="mrms" name="gender" value='2' label="ms" ></radiotrigger>
</ng-form>
```

JS document:

```
Directives.directive('radiotrigger', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            var templateText = '<li><label><input type="radio" ng-model="' + 
                    attrs.model + '" value="' + 
                    attrs.value + '">' +
                    attrs.label + '</label></li>';

            element.replaceWith(templateText);
        }
    };
});
```

thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Guess you also missed to pass the `name` attribute so only one value is selectable? On the other hand, set the `required` attribute - and the ngForm will get the `ng-invalid` and `ng-invalid-required` css classes which let you know, that your ngForm is valid.

Comment: @naeramarth7 while that appears to work, it would seem like one would then always have the radio button that is not selected set itself to invalid [(plunk)](http://plnkr.co/edit/ip0LqgIDqrn6cxYcPrJR?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

HTML

```
<ng-form name="salutationgroup">
    <radiotrigger model="mrms" name="gender" value='1' label="mr"></radiotrigger>
    <radiotrigger model="mrms" name="gender" value='2' label="ms"></radiotrigger>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="!enabled"></input>
</ng-form>
```

Directive (Observe 'ng-change="enabled=true"'):

```
Directives.directive('radiotrigger', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
        var templateText = '<li><label><input type="radio" ng-model="' + 
                attrs.model + '" value="' + 
                attrs.value + '" ng-change="enabled=true">' +
                attrs.label + '</label></li>';

        element.replaceWith(templateText);
    }
};
```

Comment: it didn´t work for me.
ok let´s make it simple.

<ng-form name="salutationgroup">
<li><label><input type="radio" ng-model="mrms" name="gender" adirectiveval value="1" ng-change= "enabled=false" >Mr</label></li>

<li><label><input type="radio" ng-model="mrms" name="gender" adirectiveval value="2" ng-change= "enabled=false" >Ms</label></li><li><label><input type="submit" ng-disabled="!enabled"></label></li></ng-form>

how can the directive in this case look like ?